# Header Files not found after doing a pod install

Tags: ios, import, cocoapods

I have the following folder structure :

```
ROOT_with_podspec
---- Classes
---- ---- Add
---- ---- Subtract
---- ---- Multiply
---- ---- Divide
```

In my podspec, I have the following line :

```
spec.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.*'
```

However, in one of the files I have an import :

```
# import "Add/Adder.h"
```

and when I do a `pod install`, the workspace doesn't pick up this path. It does pick it up when I do :

```
# import "Adder.h"
```

Can someone tell me just how I should get my workspace to find the relative paths? I've tried changing the line to :

```
spec.source_files = 'Classes/*.*'
```

But it didn't seem to work again.

Comment: I think that's normal because you are not creating the subspecs. You are adding whole source files under the Classes folder. You should create subspecs such as [cocoapods example](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `podspec`

```
spec.source_files = 'Classes/*.*'
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help preserve the relative path in the import.